# Java regex - The Escape Character Followed By The Double Backslahes Or Single?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm currently learning about the java regex and I'm a bit confused about the escape characters. I have read that the java regex is basically a two steps process, firstly the string parser processes the string and then the regex. So that's the reason why the double backslahes are needed in patterns.

However, I wonder what is the difference between the escape character followed by the double backslahes and single. For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\ntest");
```

and

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\ntest");
```

It seems to work the same, since the matcher returns true either way;

```
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("\ntest");
```

So is there any significant differences?

Comment: You may use both `\n` and `LF` patterns to match a newline. There is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

The `"\\n"` means you send `\n` string to the regex engine. See the [Java regex syntax help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\n`    The newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')

The `"\n"` means you send an LF symbol to the regex engine. Since it has no special meaning, it matches itself.

So, both `"\\n"` and `"\n"` string literals used as *regex patterns* match the same thing.